# Url/Directory as input: example.com/inputA/inputB?

Tags: javascript, directory, server

How would I set up a server to take *any* given url as *input* rather than pointing to an pre-existing directory?

ie:

```
example.com/inputA
```

returns the same content (javascript) as all other requests *but* with "inputA" as a parameter (likewise inputB: com/inputB, ect)?

is there a way to have a "virtual" directory like this? What is it called, and what server language (preferably for newbies) should I use?

Thanks.

Comment: Which server technology are you using?

Comment: @DavidTansey none. content is delivered from a static amazon s3 domain atm. I'm asking this question in preparation for making a server side script to facilitate this behavior. I know a little php and node.js, but I'm hoping for a short/simple server code that will just pass information to the page's javascript.